# When does sprint planning occur?

Tags: scrum, sprint

Does scrum planning for a iteration 2 come after or before the sprint review (demo/retrospective) of iteration 1?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [project management is now off-topic on Stack Overflow](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343829/is-stack-overflow-an-appropriate-website-to-ask-about-project-management-issues/343841#343841). Ask these questions on [SoftwareEngineering.SE](//softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) and [ProjectManagement.SE](//pm.stackexchange.com/) instead. (Unfortunately, this question is too old to be  migrated.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally the sprint review happens immediately after the sprint has finished and the planning for the next iteration comes sometime after that.

Comment: I dont see why you would do it the other way.  Wouldnt it make sense to show the demo, to add new or change functionality from that demo and incorporate it into the next sprint planning.

Comment: @MikeFlynn - Sure would.

Comment: Depends what you consider "done"  I've seen it done the other way as well.  You could finish your development work and demos but still not deploy the software to your production environment.  Some teams like to include the results of the release in your retro.

Answer (score 0):

The normal order for a sprint is this:

1. Sprint Planning
2. Dev (with Daily Scrums)
3. Sprint Review
4. Sprint Retrospective

Repeat until project complete

So, to answer your question, Sprint Planning for iteration 2 will occur after the Sprint Review and the Sprint Retrospective for Sprint 1.

Hope that helps.